# Java Spring Security login success at first and fail at second attempt

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security

i am trying to create a java spring security website but i have troubles with the login. At the first login attempt everything is fine and i am redirected to the correct page. But when i close the browser window, go to the login page and try to log in with the same user again, i am redirected to the login page. I am not able to login with the same user again but am able to login with a different user. So i can always login with a specific user once, but not twice.

At the second login attempt the following error is shown:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null"
```

Here is my SecurityConfiguration:

```
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    MySimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .permitAll()
                .successHandler(successHandler)
                .and()
                .logout();

    }

}
```

My SuccessHandler:

```
public class MySimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,   HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException  {
        Set<String> roles = AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(authentication.getAuthorities());


        if (roles.contains("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
            response.sendRedirect("consultantIndex.html");
        }
        if (roles.contains("ROLE_USER")) {
            response.sendRedirect("index.html");
        }
    }
}
```

And my UserDetailsService:

```
@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private Map<String, User> roles = new HashMap<>();

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        roles.put("admin", new User("admin", "{noop}pass", getAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")));
        roles.put("user", new User("user", "{noop}pass", getAuthority("ROLE_USER")));
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
        return roles.get(username);
    }

    private List<GrantedAuthority> getAuthority(String role) {
        return Collections.singletonList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
    }
}
```

Can someone please enlighten me why the id is "null" at the second login attempt with a specific user?

----Edit-----

I finally found the solution, i had to change the following lines of the class MyUserDetailsService to:

```
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
        User user = roles.get(username);
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.getAuthorities());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why specifically this happens only the second time, but in any case, you'll need to define a `PasswordEncoder` to let Spring Security know with what hashing function it needs to compare passwords.

The error message (`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no`PasswordEncoder`mapped for the id "null"`) is not really helpful, but is means you forgot to specify the PasswordEncoder.

If you are using BCrypt, for example, you'll need the following bean defined in your `SecurityConfiguration`.

```
@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

You can find an even more detailed explanation here, in a blog post I wrote: https://www.marcobehler.com/guides/spring-security#_authentication_with_spring_security

Comment: I added the password encoder and now i get the message "Empty encoded password" at the second login attempt :/

Comment: Ahh, I saw you already have a solution. Do keep in mind, that using {noop} is really only good for tests and shouldn't be done during production. So, you might want to switch to a real password encoder, sooner than later :)

Comment: Thx for the input, i use bCryptPasswordEncoder now :)